# How is Pega better than ser Doxis4 in BPM?

Tags: pega

I have been extensively researching about Pega and Doxis4 over the last 2 days but I could not find any comparison. I would like to know how Pega is better over Doxis4 ? Comparing several functionalities like Montiring, Rule Engine, Exception handling, Automation of Processes, Workflows, Documentation and other things

Answer (score 0):

Pega is not just BPM or a serivce consumer for any CMS, however its have lots of more functionlity in at as part of its rule engine and it have a rich UI capibility for the designer to build application.PEGA is built on JAVA and provide two ways to monitor application either write your custom JAVA beans use the PEGA provided AES tool to monitor your application.
PEGA Rule Engine is very robust and support all the BPM functionality and its been heavliy used by its customer.
Exception handling is good.
Automation of Processes--> Its has in built RPA from its latest version to automate all the basic workflow by doing some configuration and very little coding.
Documentation --> pdn.pega.com is the source for all the documentation for pega  and they are know active in community to help the developers.